# Error: IntellliSense: identifier "uint32" is undefined?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

In visual studio I am getting this error.

Error: IntellliSense: identifier "uint32" is undefined?

please suggest me which file need to include?

Comment: Have you tried e.g. [searching MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=uint32&emptyWatermark=true&searchButtonTooltip=Search%20MSDN&ac=4)?

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for `uint32_t` then you include `stdint.h`.

Otherwise, if you really are after `uint32`, then that type is not a standard type and you need to include whichever header file declares it. Only you know that information.

Comment: thnq you... just now I solved this issue by including tistdtypes.h

Comment: FWIW, that header does not define a type named `uint32`.

Comment: That header defines a type named `Uint32`. Is that the name of the type?

Comment: I still believe that my answer addresses the question that you asked. Either you are looking for the standard type, or you are looking for a type defined in your code. Now, I can tell you where to find the standard type, but I cannot really tell you where to find things in your code!

Comment: +1 @SivaramKakarla If you're looking for the standard type provided by the standard library, this ***is*** the correct answer. If it is a type in either your code or some third-party library, there isn't much that can be done without source and/or more information on the 3rd-party library.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: I was including certain header files in the wrong order, thus certain windows types weren't defined for another windows header. If you have this, try re-arranging headers too.